# changed the permission of bin to 700

Tags: boot, chmod

I changed (through chmod) the permission of /bin to 770. Now, ubuntu does not boot. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try running recovery mode. If I am not wrong it must boot. (I made the same mistake years ago)

If I am wrong, Ubuntu Disc may help you repair this too.

Answer (score 0):

Boot off a CD or get to a console and change it back to 755.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using chroot, I changed the permission back to 755.
Now, ubuntu boots but gets stucked at the "loading" screen. I am able to access shell through recovery mode but how do I load the OS?

Comment: If you changed the files in the directory to 770 as well, you'll need to change those back to 755 as well.  The symlinks should be 777.

Comment: Thanks guys. I changed the permission of files as well. Its working now.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this for future users?